# jquery popup under input text plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking for jQuery plugin that will open an html under an input text. Jest like a datepicker plugin opens a div with dates under the input text, just I need to be able create the content myself. Is there such plugin?

I prefer usage of jQuery ui since I already use this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a div with the content and then position it using the Jquery UI function: Position()

html:

```
<input type="text" id="yourTextBox" onFocus = "javascript:position()"/> 
<div id="Popup">The content that you want to see in your popup"</div>
```

css:

```
    #yourTextBox{

    }
    div#Popup{

        position: absolute;
        display: none;

    }
```

Jquery:

```
function position() {
$("#Popup").show();
        $( "#Popup" ).position({
            of: $( "#yourTextBox" ),
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom"
        });
    }
```

Demo and documentation: [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

Answer (score -1):

I've used this http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin in the past, you can set the html content programmatically and position it where you want it top/right/bottom/left.